# Integrate Android Project in my iOS project

Tags: android, ios, xcode, cocos2d-x

I have to Develop **a Game** using **Cocos2dx** for **multiplatform** purpose.Is it possible to integrate **Android** project in my **IOS project**? I am using xcode 4.2.1 for building my iOS project. please help me if anyone has done it already.Thanx in advance:)

Comment: No its not possible. Please google before SO.

Comment: @Siddharth:- according to my search its posible by using NDK, But I dnt ever use it so i ask this question

Comment: so is there any other option for creating game for multiplatform ?

Comment: Correct, no other option. I wonder if you can take a code on unix and run it on windows.

Comment: here it is, actually, I am doing this way. we publish apps on both platform using same source code. http://gameit.ro/2012/01/creating-an-iphone-and-android-cocos2d-x-hybrid-project-updated/

Comment: @Siddharth I think it is possible since both ios and android support c++, and cocos2d-x already handled the platform-specified codes. we are using it. I use xcode to write code for both platforms, but on android, you still need eclipse (on Mac) to generate apk files.

Comment: yup i already do all setup for android project even now i run simple game demo in iphone successfully and now i try to run it on android also for testing,if it run successfully in android then i will start integrate that android project in xcode.but i cant run it android because i cant set up all paths correclty.I have doubt for NDK paths or setup because i never used it

Comment: @HardikRami you may need a while to get it work (usually half a day I guess, if you understand the Android.mk and android project concept very well). because that (updated) tutorial is still old and cocos2d-x already up to 2.x and they change the folder structure a lot.

Comment: so any idea regarding updated structure?and even I m iPhone developer so i m not more idea abt all this android issues.anyway as per u suggest it is possible to integrate android project in iphone.let i wil try my best..thnx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assume you already have eclipse and ADT, android-sdk, android-ndk ready.

the basic steps is

1. use the create-android-project.sh to create an android porject first.
2. import the android project into eclipse (New-> project ->android project from existing source).
   for cocos2d 2.x
3. import the cocos2d-x java lib in to eclipse using the same way for your android project.
4. make your android project depends on cocos2d-x java project.
5. try to compile and run it on your android devices first.

if it success,

1. move your android project folder to the indicated position in that tutorial.
2. change the build_native.sh in your android project folder (correct the lib path, parent folder etc.)
3. delete your previously imported android project and import the project form the new position again.
   4.(important) right click on your project property in eclipse, make it depend on the cocos2d-x java project you imported before.

roughly it is done. you may meet bunch of problems in this process, but they will be small problems and I guess google will solve most of them.

Comment: where i  can find or import  cocos2d-x java lib? i cant undstd it

Comment: @HardikRami cocos2dx/platform/android/java

Comment: hey i m download NDK for mac run hellojni from it but i cant find libs folder in hellojni whats the reason? should i download different version of NDk?

Comment: @HardikRami you need to run build_native.sh in your android project folder.